# Averaging method (parameter variation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, perturbation-theory

Use the averaging method (parameter variation) to determine a uniform first-order approximation for:
$$ y''+y+ \epsilon y'^5=0$$
for $\epsilon\ll1$.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/622604/asymptotic-frequency-of-nonlinear-oscillator for a similar question (3rd instead of 5th power) and diverse solution approaches.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First transform into polar coordinates, $y=r\sin(\phi)$, $y'=r\cos\phi$. Then compute the derivatives in polar coordinates
\begin{align}
rr'&=y'(y''+y)=-ϵy'^6=-ϵr^6\cos^6\phi
\\
r^2\phi'&=y'^2-yy''=r^2-y(y+y'')=r^2-ϵr^6\cos^5\phi\sin\phi
\end{align}
Now take the average as $\phi$ varies over $[0,2\pi]$
\begin{align}
\bar r'&=-ϵ\bar r^5·\frac{20}{64}
\\
\bar \phi'&=1
\end{align}
so that $\bar \phi(t)=t+\phi_0$ and
$$
\bar r(t)=\frac{r(0)}{\sqrt[4]{1+\frac54ϵr(0)^4t}}.
$$